# Leaflet - get JSON properties to html

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am javascript / Leaflet beginner and I want to add some interactivity to my web map:
Map with JSON point data is included in web page. Under map is a text `<div>`, where I want to get information from points in map. 
So I need to: click on marker in map and display its name (from JSON properties) in the text below.
Can anybody help me how to do that? Thanks!

Here is (not working) example how could result look like:
http://spatialcomp.cz/click/

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a specific question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions or directions are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT: this fits your case using gson

```js
var mista = {"type":"FeatureCollection",
        "features":[
          {"type":"Feature","properties":{"ID":1},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-72.6936149597168,19.45777124789975]}},
          {"type":"Feature","properties":{"ID":2},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-72.68546104431152,19.45170148462148]}},
          {"type":"Feature","properties":{"ID":3},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-72.67576217651367,19.44846418467642]}},
          {"type":"Feature","properties":{"ID":4},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-72.69455909729002,19.44789765054524]}},
        ]
      }
  
      //create a function, that is bound to one point of your features
      function onEachFeature(features, layer) {
        //check if your feature has all properties, you want to display
        if(features.properties.ID && features.geometry.coordinates) {
          //create a click event for each point
          layer.on("click", function(e) {
            document.getElementById('pravy').innerHTML =
              "coordinates: " + features.geometry.coordinates + "</br> ID: " 
                + features.properties.ID;
          });
        }
      }

      var dataHaiti = L.geoJson(mista, 
          {
            //bind the function as option to each layer
            onEachFeature: onEachFeature    
          }).addTo($scope.map);
```

http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html

---

### This is the simplest way if you only have a few markers

assuming you created your map something like this:

```js
var map = L.map("map");
```

and a marker like this:

```js
var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(11.145673, 48.890023)).addTo(map);
```

then you can add an onClick event to the marker like that:

```js
marker.on('click', getLatLngOfClick);

function getLatLngOfClick(e) {
  //get the coordinates of the click event
  var lat = e.latnlng.lat;
  var lng = e.latlng.lng;
  
  //now you can work with the variables, however you like
  //
  //insert your code below
  }
```

---

Comment: Markers are created from JSON, properties are: symbol (just for icons), name (name of place). Can you help me how to extract name into variable? And then insert into paragraph out of the map.

Comment: can you edit your question and add some code of yours. this would be very helpful for all of us :)

Comment: ok, i added link, how could result look. Thanks :-)

Comment: I edited my answer for you, it worked for me. So if it works for you, too, please accept it ;)

Comment: It's perfect, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you need to create marker with click event

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-click

and in the event extract data from properties, then insert them somehow (with jQuery, for example, if you want simplicity)

What exactly is your problem with that? (you can comment on my post)

Comment: Yes, extract data (for example - name of point) and insert it out of the map, in any paragraph below. But because my elementary knowledge of JS, i don't know how this works and what code use.